# AWS - Using Boto3 to get last x Lambda Run Status

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am wondering what the best way of getting the last 'x' results for AWS Lambda invocations are?

I have the following python code:

```
    client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

    response = client.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace='AWS/Lambda',
        MetricName='Invocations',
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'FunctionName',
                'Value': name
            }
        ],
        StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=10800),
        EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
        Period=1,
        Statistics=['Average'],
        Unit='Count'
    )
```

The only issue is it is returning to many events:

`InvalidParameterCombinationException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the GetMetricStatistics operation: You have requested up to 10,800 datapoints, which exceeds the limit of 1,440. You may reduce the datapoints requested by increasing Period, or decreasing the time range.`

Even though the function has only been ran a handful of times.

Is there any way to get the 'last x lambda invocations' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach for this is to just use cloudwatch logs - Lambda outputs standard start/end logs to the log group for cloudwatch, which should be easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

Datapoints are not the same as invocations. Datapoints are points in time when Cloudwatch has some record about metric, even if nothing happened for some time Cloudwatch will still query Lambda service for new data.

What you want to use for this request is pagination: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Paginator.GetMetricData

I'm not 100% sure it will solve problem, but it's a good first step before considering narrowing down time frame.

Answer (score 0):

As @Oleksii eluded to, if you want metric_data you should be using the get_metric_data command. Additionally, looking at the documentation you should be using 'Sum' as your Stat value if what you are wanting is total invocations in a time period. Your period value looks off too, as the documentation states lambda sends metrics to cloudwatch in 1 minute (60 second) intervals.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html